# document.execCommand('SaveAs',null,'filename.csv') is not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Right now am using save as command as follows in my client side js file

```
    var csvWindow = window.open("", "_blank");
    csvWindow.document.open('text/html');
    csvWindow.document.write(text);
    csvWindow.document.execCommand('SaveAs', null, 'data.csv');
    csvWindow.close();
```

Am not able to save the page when I am trying to save the page using the above command in Google Chrome.

when the above one is execute "Save As" dialog is supposed to come but am not getting any dialog like that.

it is working fine in IE 11 where as it not working in Chrome.

Please provide inputs on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `document.execCommand('saveas')` functionality is supported only in **IE** and is not supported in **Chrome** and **Mozila**.

You can force the `SaveAs` using *http header*. You have to include the following header in HTTP response of the file to be downloaded:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<file name.ext>"`

Where `<file name.ext>` is the filename you want to appear in SaveAs dialog (like `finances.xls` or `mortgage.pdf`) - without `< and >` symbols.

More info can be found in this [link](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html).

Comment: thanks barr for the info, but for me data is creating in client side itself and there is no where http request comes into the picture for me, updated my question how am executing the saveas command in my js file